# socket.io server deployed on an nginx server handles a few connections until crash

Tags: nginx, socket.io, nestjs

i deployed a socket io server in a nestjs backend it works but when it have about 10 - 15 connections it crashes and stops handling connections

this is my nginx conf

````
    server_name XXX.dev;
location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8002;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

  location ~* \.io {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy false;

      proxy_pass http://localhost:8002;
      proxy_redirect off;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}```

i tried to config my nginx server with de socket.io docs but it keeps failing
````